# How to calculate the force exerted by pressure on hot air balloon envelope fabric?

Tags: balloon

How to calculate the force of hot air balloon envelope fabric?
and how to select a fabric which can bear this force?
For example, a spherality balloon:

- $r=10~m$
- $T_1=100~°C$
- $ρ_1=0.95~kg/m^3$
- $T_2=20~°C$
- $ρ_2=1.25~kg/m^3$
- $m=1000~kg$

Where:

- $r$ is the  radii of the balloon, in m
- $T_1$ is the temperature of balloon inside atmosphere, in Celsius
- $ρ_1$ is the density of the balloon inside atmosphere, in  kg/m3
- $T_2$ is the temperature of balloon outside atmosphere, in Celsius
- $ρ_2$ is the density of the balloon outside atmosphere, in  kg/m3
- $m$ is the total weight of the balloon(including balloon all equipment and persons)

Comment: Hi! As this stands it sounds like you're trying to get us to do your homework. Could you perhaps elaborate what you have tried to do to solve the question on your own? You're also best of splitting this question (forces/materials) into two separate ones.

Comment: This looks more like a physics homework than anything else.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142697/the-physics-behind-balloons-lifting-objects/142698#142698